# How to add links of a custom image sizes in wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, image, attachment, image-size

I am using `add_image_size()` function to add custom image sizes in wordpress and want to show downloadable link of any image size in single post. If you don't understand what I want to say please take a look at the following website.

http://www.alliphonewallpapers.com/iphone-wallpaper/id/3238/

It save images in different sizes and add link of that size in its post. I also want to add links of different image size. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to obtain thumbnail URL. Look at Wordpress Codex, there is an example that perfectly fits your needs and it even shows given URL only if given thumbnail size is available:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_large_Image_Size